# Error: updates without prompting for location authorization

Tags: ios

2015-04-07 13:26:10.767 harita[1690:821533] Trying to start MapKit location `updates without prompting for location authorization. Must call -[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization] or -[CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization] first.`

Comment: first thing you need to do is to add one or both of the following keys to your Info.plist file:  NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription,
   NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription

Comment: http://nshipster.com/core-location-in-ios-8/

Comment: are you getting alert for the permission .

Answer (score 0):

in ios8 you have to write below code

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
// Code to check if the app can respond to the new selector found in iOS 8. If so, request it.
if([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
    [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    // Or [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}

[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

And you also have to add NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription and message you want to display for your app in your plist file.

Check this tutorial http://www.devfright.com/ios-6-core-location-tutorial/